# Sqlalchemy mySQL optimize query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, performance, sqlalchemy

**General:**

I need to create a statistic tool from a given DB with many hundreds of thousands entries. So I never need to write to the DB, only get data.

**Problem:**

I have a user table, in my case i select `20k` users (between two dates). Now I need to select only users, who at least spent money once (from these `20k`).

To do so I have 3 different tables where the data is saved whether a user spent money. (So we work here with 4 tables in total):

```
User, Transaction_1, Transaction_2, Transaction_3
```

**What I did so far:**

In the model of the User class I have created a property which checks whether the user appears once in one of the Transaction tables:

```
@property
def spent_money_once(self):
    spent_money_atleast_once = False
    in_transactions = Transaction_1.query.filter(Transaction_1.user_id == self.id).first()
    if in_transactions:
        spent_money_atleast_once = True
        return spent_money_atleast_once
    in_transactionsVK = Transaction_2.query.filter(Transaction_2.user_id == self.id).first()
    if in_transactionsVK:
        spent_money_atleast_once = True
        return spent_money_atleast_once
    in_transactionsStripe = Transaction_3.query.filter(Transaction_3.user_id == self.id).first()
    if in_transactionsStripe:
        spent_money_atleast_once = True
        return spent_money_atleast_once
    return spent_money_atleast_once
```

Then I created two counters for male and female users, so I can count how many of these 20k users spent money at least once:

```
males_payed_atleast_once = 0
females_payed_atleast_once = 0

for male_user in male_users.all():
    if male_user.spent_money_once is True:
        males_payed_atleast_once += 1

for female_user in female_users.all():
    if female_user.spent_money_once is True:
        females_payed_atleast_once += 1
```

But this takes really long to calculate, arround 40-60 min. I have never worked with such huge data amounts, maybe it is normal?

**Additional info:**

In case you wonder how `male_users` and `female_users` look like:

```
# Note: is this even efficient, if all() completes the query than I need to store the .all() into variables, otherwise everytime I call .all() it takes time
global all_users
global male_users
global female_users

all_users = Users.query.filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date)
male_users = Users.query.filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == "1")
female_users = Users.query.filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == "2")
```

I am trying to save certain queries in global variables to improve performance.

I am using Python 3 | Flask | Sqlalchemy for this task. The DB is MySQL.

Comment: What is the significance of the 3 transaction tables?  Do you need to count repeats in _each_ table?  Or only in the combination of all 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed now a completely different approach and used `join` and it is now way faster, it completes the query in 10 sec, which took 60 min.~:

```
# males
paying_males_1 = male_users.join(Transaction_1, Transaction_1.user_id == Users.id).all()
paying_males_2 = male_users.join(Transaction_2, Transaction_2.user_id == Users.id).all()
paying_males_3 = male_users.join(Transaction_3, Transaction_3.user_id == Users.id).all()

males_payed_all = paying_males_1 + paying_males_2 + paying_males_3
males_payed_atleast_once = len(set(males_payed_all))
```

I am simply joining each table and use `.all()`, the results are simple `lists`. After that I am merging all lists and typecasting them to `set`. Now I have only the unique users. The last step is to count them by using `len()` on the `set`.

Comment: You can get amount of records using `count()`. example: `male_payed_count = Users.query.filter(Users.date_added >= start_date, Users.date_added <= end_date, Users.gender == "1", Users.spent_money_once == True).count()`. without `len` and `set`

Comment: This sadly does not work, I also tried it, but it does not count anything. It returns 0 for male and female

Comment: This can probably be doen with a hybrid_property, but after changing to hybrid I got weird results, it simply counted all records ignoring spent_money == True. I leave it as it is for now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to aggregate the info of the 3 tables together before counting, this will be a bit faster:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(ct) AS total
  FROM (
    ( SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM trans1 GROUP BY userid )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM trans2 GROUP BY userid )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM trans3 GROUP BY userid )
       )
  GROUP BY userid
  HAVING total >= 2
```

Recommend you test this in the mysql commandline tool, then figure out how to convert it to Python 3 | Flask | Sqlalchemy

Funny thing about packages that "hide the database" --; you still need to understand how the database works if you are going to do anything non-trivial.